# Mac Java Crashed Error

Tags: java, macos, crash, jdeveloper

I am using a OS X v 10.8.4 with Java 1.6.0_51 installed.When i try to open Jdeveloper java application it crash upon loading. I got the following message in the log file

```
 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[131]: ([0x0-0x53053].com.oracle.JDeveloper[680]) Exited with code: 2
```

Is this what might be causing the crash?

Comment: You probably mean 1.6.0_51, right? Have you tried launching it from the command line?

Comment: @fge yeah sorry. Typo. How can i launch developer from command line?

Comment: You need to find that command line, however with Mac OS X I have no idea how to do that, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which JDeveloper version you are trying to use.
Check out the installation guide for JDev for specific Mac instructions - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/index.html